Extracting semi-transparent coloured overlay from complex background
I'm looking to extract a coloured and semi-transparent overlay from two image captures from a game. I've used a frame debugger to extract two copies of the exact same frame, one with the overlay and one without:


I've tried many times so far, attempting with different blend modes like divide, subtract, etc. and extra image manipulation with blender's image compositing capabilities. However, the only semi-decent result I got was using GIMP's Color Erase blend mode which gave me this:

However, there is still the issue with the window frames showing through the semi-transparent areas.
Would it be possible to cleanly extract the overlay without any articats and if so, how?
I'm not very experienced with graphic design/image manupilation so more in-depth explanations would be appreciated
(Edit: Color Erase not Color Extract)

I would say no, just mathematically. Basically, there’s no way for GIMP to know if a slight difference between the overlay and the original scene is because of semi transparency or full opacity and happenstance. I think your best bet is just trying to re-create the graphic given the mostly correct extraction as a reference.
